# Methodology to generate conditionally independent data correct?

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, independence, multivariate-normal-distribution, conditioning

I am trying to generate samples from continuous distributions that are conditionally independent.  More specifically, I would like to generate samples from the following joint distribution $f(x,y,z)$ such that $f(x,y|z) = f(x|z) \times f(y|z)$.  For now, I would like to simulate this with Gaussian random variables, although later I plan on expanding it to be more general with the use of copulas.  My question is, how do I properly generate this data?

Here is what I have tried (I can provide Matlab code if people are interested, but I tried to abstract this post from specific implementations).

1. For the sake of this example, suppose that $Cov(X,Z) = \Sigma_1$ and $Cov(Y,Z) = \Sigma_2$.
2. Generate samples from $f(x,z)$ via existing functions such as Matlab's [mvnrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html).  This gives me a 2-D matrix, say $M_1$.
3. Slice the matrix to get the $Z$ values only.
4. Generate samples of $Y$ by sampling from the normal distribution.
5. Combine the samples of $Y$ and $Z$ into a new 2-D matrix, call it $M_2$.
6. Multiply $M_2$ by the Cholesky root of $\Sigma_2$ to correlate $Y$ and $Z$ as desired by $\Sigma_2$.
7. Samples from $f(x,y,z)$ would then be $[M_1(:,1) M_2(:,2) M_1(:,1)]$ -- this is just Matlab matrix slicing notation, but I get $X$ from $M_1$, $Y$ from $M_2$, and $Z$ from $M_1$ again (although it *should* be no different if I got it from $M_2$?)

I have somewhat tested this by generating samples in this way, and computing the partial correlation coefficient of the generated data, and it shows that there is no partial correlation between X and Y, but there is a partial correlation between X and Z, and Y and Z, as expected.

Does anybody have insight into whether this methodology is appropriate, or did I just get lucky in this case?  I chose to use the Gaussian model here, because of the property that correlation is equivalent to independence.

Comment: Step 6 is simply: generate $Y$ conditional on $Z$, here the same thing as conditional on $X$ and $Z$. The simulated $Y$ can be obtained as well as $a Z + U$ where $U$ is independent of $Z$ with suitable variance.

Comment: @Yves To dissect your first sentence, you are saying that because $X$ is dependent upon $Z$, and then generating $Y$ from $Z$ renders the fact that $Y$ will be conditional upon both $X$ and $Z$?  I hadn't thought about it from this perspective before.


Regarding your second sentence, you are saying that $Y$ can also be generated as $Y = aZ + U$.  This comes from the fact that you specified $U$ to be independent of $Z$, and we know that if $U \sim Gaussian$ and $Z \sim Gaussian$, then $U + Z$ will be Gaussian also?  Although choosing $var(U)$ may be tricky to get the desired $\Sigma_2$?

Comment: For the first point: yes. For the second point, the Cholesky root does the job, yet $aZ$ is nothing but $E[Y|Z]$, while $U$ is the residual $Z-E[Y|Z]$ so $a$ and $\text{Var}(U)$ are available in a standard formula. All this would work with vectors $X$, $Y$, $Z$ using a matrix in place of $a$.

Comment: Sorry, a typo in my coment:  the residual is of course $Y- E[Y|Z]$